# curves and constant length

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Find all curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ having the following property: the segment of the normal straight line between curve and the x axis has constant length.

If $\alpha (t)=(x(t),y(t))$, I found $y(t)=\pm \sqrt{C/(1+(k(t))^2)}$, where $k(t)$ is the curvature and C is the constant. How to continue?

Comment: If the tangent segment has constant length you get a well known example called the tractrix. For your problem, it appears only horizontal lines work.

Comment: Circumferences with origin on the x-axis also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice problem. Here is my approach. It is just a sketch of proof:

Suppose $\alpha$ is parameterized with arc lenght parameter, ie. $(x')^2+(y')^2=1$ .

The required property implies that:

$$
|| (x(t),y(t)) -\; (x(t)+\frac{y(t)y'(t)}{x'(t)},0)||^2=\frac{(yy')^2}{(x')^2}+y^2=k \mbox{ a constant}
$$

Then $y^2(t)=k^2 (x')^2$ and therefore $y^2=k^2-(y')^2$. Solving this differential equation we get the curves (circumferences and horizontal lines).

Comment: I don't understant the final part. Why $y^2(t)=k^2(x')^2$ and $y^2=k^2-(y')^2$?

Comment: Multiply by $(x')^2$ and use that $(x')^2+(y')^2=1$.